# How do I log visits to a certain subdirectory of my website?

Tags: apache, logging, traffic

I have a simple apache server (the default installation on Digitalocean). I can view visits to the domain in the /var/log/apache2 directory, but how do I see which subdirectory they viewed? If this isn't something that's logged by default, how should I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a logfile for all requests the server processed.

RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora Linux Apache access file location is:

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
```

Debian / Ubuntu Linux Apache access log file location is:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
```

FreeBSD Apache access log file location is:

```
/var/log/httpd-access.log
```

By default, there you can find the IP address, time, request method, URL the client was using to access your server and browser user agent.

If you want a customized log file you can always visit the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) - AccessLog.